# binding click javascript to asp:button stops button working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, event-handling, code-behind

This is strange as a swear it was working last night!

I have the following HTML Markup: (portion of)

```
<div id="doButtonContainer">
    <asp:button id="resizeActionButton" runat="server" onclick="doResize"  class="doResize redButton" text="Do Resize" />
</div>
<div id="res" runat="server"></div>
```

and the following code behind page

```
Partial Class Admin_webSite_reSampleImgs
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Sub doResize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles resizeActionButton.Click  '=== THIS FUNCTION DETERMINES THE IMAGES TO CHANGE...

        '// DO STUFF //

        res.InnerHtml = "DONE" '"<b>Products: </b><hr/> " & Replace(ids.TrimEnd(","), ",", ", ") & " <hr/> <b>Have been updated</b> <hr/>"
    End Sub
```

I then have this javascript:

```
$('input.doResize').bind('click', function (e) {
    if (simpleValidate('') <= 0) {
        // do things before submit
    } else {
        e.preventdefault();
        alert("not all fields complete");
    };
});
```

Firstly, I am not sure whether I need the `handles` condition on the code behind, or the `onclick` attribute on the button, either/or/both I am not sure.

Secondly... all the `Javascript` works, but the code behind is not being called.

I swear it did last night though!

Very confused... what have I done wrong?!

Comment: The Javascript is working fine, it's the VB code behind which isnt

Answer (score 0):

use onclientclick:

```
<asp:button id="resizeActionButton" runat="server" onclick="doResize" OnClientClick="return checkValid();"  class="doResize redButton" text="Do Resize" />
```

javascript function:

```
    function checkValid(){
    if (simpleValidate('') <= 0) {
        // do things before submit
        return true;
    } else {
        e.preventdefault();
        alert("not all fields complete");
        return false;
    };
}
```

Comment: That tidies up my Javascript a bit, but it's not the problem. The Javascript is working fine, but the Code Behind is not. I'm getting no errors, my validation script works, but the VB code is not being processed.

Comment: You should use OnClientClick for javascript function. If OnClientClick function return true, the VB code will fire.

Comment: The VB code won't fire though! Nevermind... I've changed the whole thing into an AJAX call now and it all works as a Web Method. I can't get the Server Side button to work, so I'm not using it anymore!